# Where are contract names stored?

Tags: contract-development, etherscan

I see Etherscan and DeBank display the names of various contracts. Are those contract names in the metadata of the contract itself or are those all just from the Etherscan contract registry?

Answer (score 1):

On Etherscan you can verify your contract’s code and add a name to it. It’s not saved inside the contract. See:

https://etherscan.io/contractsVerified

**Note**: There are some cases like ERC20 that the contract contains a name but of course it’s not always the case.